# Combobox checked items showing as [object, Object] and not String value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, combobox, checkedlistbox

I have the following code for a checklist inside a ComboBox:

```
<sq8:ComboBox runat="server" ID="ComboBox1" CheckBoxes="True" CheckedItemsTexts="DisplayAllInInput" Width="340px" OnClientItemChecked="ShowAlert"><Items>
      <sq8:ComboBoxItem runat="server" Value="Yes" Text="Yes"></sq8:ComboBoxItem>
      <sq8:ComboBoxItem runat="server" Value="No" Text="No"></sq8:ComboBoxItem>
      <sq8:ComboBoxItem runat="server" Value="Maybe" Text="Maybe"></sq8:ComboBoxItem>
      </Items>
    </sq8:ComboBox>
    <sq:BindableControl runat="server" TargetControlID="ComboBox1" DataField="ComboBox1"></sq:BindableControl>
```

I have the following simple JavaScript to get the checkeditems, in an alert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowAlert() {

var combobox = $findByControlId("ComboBox1").get_checkedItems();


alert(combobox);


}

</script>
```

I added the function to the OnClientItemChecked property on the ComboBox but when I test this, the alert shows the values as:

```
[object Object]
```

I tried adding ".ToString" to the end of the alert:

```
alert(combobox.ToString);
```

This then showed the checkeditems as "undefined" instead of "[object Object]"

I'm a bit lost. Could anyone help? The datatype for the ComboBox in my datamodel is String. Should it be something else?

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ID value from ASP will be re-generated to have different value with what we entered in the aspx. So I guess adding `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the ComboBox should be helpful. ref: https://forums.asp.net/t/1882057.aspx?How+to+give+Static+id+for+asp+net+controls+

Answer (score 0):

Try:
var combobox = $findByControlId("ComboBox1").get_checkedItems().get_text());